# Trying to link static lib in MonoTouch, get "Error: You should provide one root assembly only"

Tags: iphone, mono, xamarin.ios

I need to create some functions in native code that are called from my MonoTouch app. I've tried a lot of variations to get this working, but I always get, **"Error: You should provide one root assembly only"** when I try to build.

Here are the steps I've taken to try this:

**Create a simple MyFile.cpp file:**

```
extern "C"
{
   int TestAdd( int a, int b );
}

int TestAdd( int a, int b )
{
    return a+b;
}
```

**Build that into a .a file:**

> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2
>   -arch armv6 -c MyFile.cpp
>
> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/libtool
>   -static -arch_only armv6 MyFile.o -o libtest.a

**Copy libtest.a into my MonoTouch project's folder and add it to the project.**

**Under Project Options->iPhone Build, set Extra arguments to "-ltest".**

.. and I keep getting "Error: You should provide one root assembly only". I haven't even used the DllImport("__Internal")) attribute or tried to call TestAdd inside my code yet.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6):

Your extra arguments are wrong, they should be something like:

-gcc_flags "-L${ProjectDir} -ltest -force_load ${ProjectDir}/libtest.a"

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I changed the name of the base folder which contained .sln file and hence I was getting this error. I changed the root folder back to earlier one and the error got fixed.